# Kafka JDBC Sink Connector : optional fields in schema

Tags: json, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I have a topic where transmit records that will be consumed by a kafka jdbc sink connector (into Postgres). These records are **upsert** into a database and might be produced without all fields especially when it is an **update**.

However, as seen in another [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54139986/kafka-jdbc-sink-connector-gives-a-null-pointer-exception-for-message-with-schema), "the value[s] for fields, that are marked as optional ha[ve] to be in message payload.".

Some of my records mean for update are not "complete" like in the following example :
I have a record as : `User(name: string, age: int)` and want to update its age, our system will only produce :

```
{
    "schema": {
        "type": "struct",
        "fields": [{
                "field": "name",
                "type": "string",
                "optional": true
            },
            {
                "field": "age",
                "type": "int64",
                "optional": true
            }
        ]
    },
    "payload": {
        "age": 33
    }
}
```

From what I understood, the jdbc connector will be able to **only** update fields present in the payload, is it correct?

Also, is it alright to only produce a schema that matches the payload? ie : We would only have "age" in the schema of this record.

Comment: And you're against adding null because you think it'll update all columns? Also, how does that payload designate **what** needs updated? Do you only have one row in that table?

Comment: indeed in this *example*, the payload designate what needs updated. If I only want to update the "age", I will only produce the updated field. And in this example my table would represent the schema with 2 columns "name" and "age"